# Dynamic use of viewswitcher / viewflipper

Tags: android, viewflipper, viewswitcher

I have a file toto.xml with a layout that contains a TextView and a ImageView.
and I have another file main.xml that contains a ViewSwitcher.

the question:
How to integrate toto.xml in ViewSwitcher dynamically with different content and editable in the Main.java

thank you

PS: Sorry if my English is poor but this text is translated by Google Translator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more than a week of research :

when the firstly ViewSwitcher can only have two views on this we must use the ViewFlipper
secondly: to fill a ViewSwitcher by more views that can scroll it is very simple:

```
flipper.addView (View v);
```

knowing that the View can be a TextView or even a LinearLayout which contains one or more textview, so we can use a loop that will fill the view from the database and then call switcher.addView ();

Example:

```
ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);  

flipper.addView (addText("Stackoverflow Forever"));

public View addText(String text) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(text);
return v;
}
```

Thank you anyway;)